# Mongoose match element or empty array with $in statement

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to select any documents where privacy settings match the provided ones and any documents which do not have any privacy settings (i.e. public).

Current behavior is that if I have a schema with an array of object ids referenced to another collection:

```js
privacy: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Category',
    index: true,
    required: true,
    default: []
}],
```

And I want to filter all content for my categories and the public ones, in our case content that does not have a privacy settings. i.e. an empty array []

We currently query that with an or query

```js
{"$or":[
    {"privacy": {"$size": 0}},
    {"privacy": {"$in":
        ["5745bdd4b896d4f4367558b4","5745bd9bb896d4f4367558b2"]}
    }
]}
```

I would love to query it by only providing an empty array [] as one the comparison options in the $in statement. Which is possible in mongodb:

```js
db.emptyarray.insert({a:1})
db.emptyarray.insert({a:2, b:null})
db.emptyarray.insert({a:2, b:[]})
db.emptyarray.insert({a:3, b:["perm1"]})
db.emptyarray.insert({a:3, b:["perm1", "perm2"]})
db.emptyarray.insert({a:3, b:["perm1", "perm2", []]})
> db.emptyarray.find({b:[]})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a305f3dd89e8a887e629ce0"), "a" : 2, "b" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a305f3dd89e8a887e629ce3"), "a" : 3, "b" : [ "perm1", "perm2", [ ] ] }
> db.emptyarray.find({b:{$in:[]}})
> db.emptyarray.find({b:{$in:[[], "perm1"]}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a305f3dd89e8a887e629ce0"), "a" : 2, "b" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a305f3dd89e8a887e629ce1"), "a" : 3, "b" : [ "perm1" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a305f3dd89e8a887e629ce2"), "a" : 3, "b" : [ "perm1", "perm2" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a305f3dd89e8a887e629ce3"), "a" : 3, "b" : [ "perm1", "perm2", [ ] ] }
> db.emptyarray.find({b:{$in:[[], "perm1", null]}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a305f3dd89e8a887e629cde"), "a" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a305f3dd89e8a887e629cdf"), "a" : 2, "b" : null }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a305f3dd89e8a887e629ce0"), "a" : 2, "b" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a305f3dd89e8a887e629ce1"), "a" : 3, "b" : [ "perm1" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a305f3dd89e8a887e629ce2"), "a" : 3, "b" : [ "perm1", "perm2" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a305f3dd89e8a887e629ce3"), "a" : 3, "b" : [ "perm1", "perm2", [ ] ] }
> db.emptyarray.find({b:{$in:[[]]}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a305f3dd89e8a887e629ce0"), "a" : 2, "b" : [ ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a305f3dd89e8a887e629ce3"), "a" : 3, "b" : [ "perm1", "perm2", [ ] ] }
```

Maybe like this:

```js
"privacy_locations":{
     "$in": ["5745bdd4b896d4f4367558b4","5745bd9bb896d4f4367558b2",[]]
}
```

But this query, works from the console (CLI), but not in the code where it throws a cast error:

```js
{
    "message":"Error in retrieving records from db.", 
    "error":
        {
        "message":"Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"[]\" at ...
        }
}
```

Now I perfectly understand the cast is happening because the Schema is defined as an ObjectId.

But I still find that this approach is missing two possible scenarios.

I believe it is possible to query (in MongoDB) null options or empty array within an $in statement.

`array: {$in:[null, [], [option-1, option-2]}`

Is this correct?

I've been thinking that the best solution to my problem (Cannot select in options or empty) could be to have empty arrays be an array with a fix option of ALL for example. A setting for privacy that means ALL instead of how it is now which is that if not set, that is considered all.

But I don't want a major refactor of the existing code, I just need to see if I can make a better query or more performant query.

Today we have the query working with an $OR statement that has issues with indexes. And even if it is fast, I wanted to bring attention to this issue even if is not considered a bug.

I will appreciate any comments or guidance.

Answer (score 0):

The semi-short answer is that the schema is mixing types for the `privacy` property (`ObjectId` and `Array`) while declaring that it is strictly of type `ObjectId` in the schema.

Since MongoDB is schema-less it will allow any document shape per document and doesn't need to verify the query document to match a schema. Mongoose on the other hand is meant to apply a schema enforcement and so it will verify a query document against the schema before it attempts to query the DB. The query document for `{ privacy: { $in: [[]] } }` will fail validation since an empty array is not a valid `ObjectId` as indicated by the error.

The schema would need to declare the type as `Mixed` (which doesn't support `ref`) to continue using an empty array as an acceptable type as well as `ObjectId`.

```
// Current
const FooSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  privacy: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Category',
    index: true,
    required: true,
    default: []
  }]
});

const Foo = connection.model('Foo', FooSchema);

const foo1 = new Foo();
const foo2 = new Foo({privacy: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId()]});

Promise.all([
  foo1.save(),
  foo2.save()
]).then((results) => {
  console.log('Saved', results);
  /*
  [
    { __v: 0, _id: 5a36e36a01e1b77cba8bd12f, privacy: [] },
    { __v: 0, _id: 5a36e36a01e1b77cba8bd131, privacy: [ 5a36e36a01e1b77cba8bd130 ] }
  ]
  */

  return Foo.find({privacy: { $in: [[]] }}).exec();
}).then((results) => {
  // Never gets here
  console.log('Found', results);
}).catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
  // { [CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "[]" at path "privacy" for model "Foo"] }
});
```

And the working version. *Also note the adjustment to properly apply the required flag, index flag and default value.*

```
// Updated
const FooSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  privacy: {
    type: [{
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed
    }],
    index: true,
    required: true,
    default: [[]]
  }
});

const Foo = connection.model('Foo', FooSchema);

const foo1 = new Foo();
const foo2 = new Foo({
  privacy: [mongoose.Types.ObjectId()]
});

Promise.all([
  foo1.save(),
  foo2.save()
]).then((results) => {
  console.log(results);
  /*
    [
      { __v: 0, _id: 5a36f01733704f7e58c0bf9a, privacy: [ [] ] },
      { __v: 0, _id: 5a36f01733704f7e58c0bf9c, privacy: [ 5a36f01733704f7e58c0bf9b ] }
    ]
  */

  return Foo.find().where({
    privacy: { $in: [[]] }
  }).exec();
}).then((results) => {
  console.log(results);
  // [ { _id: 5a36f01733704f7e58c0bf9a, __v: 0, privacy: [ [] ] } ]
});
```

Comment: "The query document for { privacy: { $in: [[]] } } will fail validation since an empty array is not a valid ObjectId as indicated by the error." 

I don't think [] is suppose to indicate an ObjectID. Which is the content of the array. An array of 0 ObjectIds is an EMPTY ARRAY [].

And I think the $in statement si going through the options given, if it contains an objectid or in this case a string, because string is not an ObjectId either right?
So through the Options is casting to ObjectId, and an Option of NULL or Empty Array should be able to be evaluated. if privacy is null is not OID

Comment: From mongo's documentation for `$in`: "_If the field holds an array, then the `$in` operator selects the documents whose field holds an array that contains at least one element that matches a value in the specified array (e.g. <value1>, <value2>, etc.)_". This means that mongo will iterate through the array attempting to equality match the elements from the array to any of the array values of the queried document property. Since the schema declared that the property is an array of ObjectIds, Mongoose attempts to cast all values in the query document to ObjectIds hence why it errors.

Comment: if privacy is emtpy [] like {privacy:[]}, $in[[], ObjectId('xxxx')] matches [] because it is the value of privacy. 
You where clause and results are NOT what I require. I've added CLI example.
If Foo.find().where({privacy: { $in: [[]] }}) should have returned only one doc, as only one doc has an empty array, the other one has an array with an instance of ObjectId.
Allow me to write it differently.
If I say that privacy is of type ObjectId it can be an objectid or null. If it is an Array of OIDs, it can be Null, [], or hold value. It doesn't need a mixed type to hold those 3 values.